# Is it possible for a currently running TeamCity build to detect that it is a "history build"?

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible for a currently running TeamCity build to detect that it is a "history build" through a build parameter or api call? I have build configurations that end by publishing a NuGet package and would like to hold off on publishing if a "History build" is detected. TeamCity server seems to already detect this state as the running build is shown as gray.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-BuildRequests). Something like `http://MyTeamCity/app/rest/builds/BUILD_ID`.

To get the `BUILD_ID` of the current build, use `%teamcity.build.id%` (the TeamCity parameter).

The call returns XML with details about the given build. If historical, there's a `history="true"` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

My team was having similar issues with history builds and nuget packages. Using the tips from sferencik, I was able to put together the following PowerShell script that runs as the first step of all of our build projects (be sure and set the PowerShell runner option for "Format stderr output as" to error). This will cause the build to stop when it detects a history build.

```
Write-Host "Checking for history build."

$buildUrl = "%teamcity.serverUrl%/app/rest/builds/%teamcity.build.id%"

Write-Host "URL for build data is $buildUrl"

$wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$cred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("%system.teamcity.auth.userId%", "%system.teamcity.auth.password%")
$wc.Credentials = $cred

[xml]$buildXml = $wc.DownloadString($buildUrl)

$isHistory = $buildXml.build.GetAttribute("history") -eq "true"

if ($isHistory) {
    Write-Host "##teamcity[buildProblem description='This is a history build and is being abandoned.']"
    Write-Error "Build is history" 
} else {
    Write-Host "Build is not history"
}
```